# session.add() and session methods does not exist

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using SqlAlchemy 1.3.20 and python3.8

In below code i used class `sessionmaker`.than i created an object.

when i call object methods such as : add() , commit() , query() and etc

i see this error `TypeError: "Session' object is not callable`.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Sessionmaker,relationship


base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///c:\\users\\alierza\\desktop\\python\\instagram\\test.db',echo=True)


class Cars(base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    make = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    color = Column(String(50), nullable=False)


class carOweners(base):
    __tablename__ = 'carowner'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    age = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    carid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('cars.id'))
    car = relationship('Cars')


Session=sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session=Session()

base.metadata.create_all(engine)


car1=Cars(make='Ford',color='siliver')
owenr1=carOweners(name='Joe',age=20,carid=(car1.id))

session().add(car1)
session().add(owenr1)
session().commit()
```

its seems that methods does not exist.
Any tips or help?

Comment: `session.add(..)`, not `session().add(...)`- you don't need the parentheses directly after `session`.

Comment: After i removed parentheses i see this error:         Instance of 'Session' has no 'add' member             and : Instance of 'Session' has no 'commit' member